# Why is SSH/SFTP failing for commands with larger returns?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, sftp

We have a SFTP server which was working fine until we added another ISP. The connection to the SFTP server is not going through the new ISP, I confirmed it with `tracert`. No change was made on the server either. But since then, some users' SFTP or SSH connections time out/hang if the executed command has a larger return. Here's the scenario:

1. I can continue to ping and the ping will always return even when
   SSH/SFTP times out
2. I can connect to the server, it asks for authentication and lets me
   log in.
3. If the `ls` command for my root directory is returning a small
   number of files or folders, then it shows the listing of files and
   folders
4. If the `ls` command for my root directory is larger than let's say 5
   or 6 files or folders, then it hangs/times out.
5. While trying this, I tried running a ping to the server, and it's
   returning all the time.
6. This doesn't happen to everyone, but it seems to happen to users who are in another city..
7. I tried different SFTP clients (FileZilla and WinSCP). Both have
   the same issue.

I ran WireShark on my PC (which is outside of our network and outside of the city), when SFTP/SSH times out, I see retransmission and part of segment not captured errors coming up, which leads me to believe there might be some packet loss somewhere between the hops.

```
Expert Info (Note/Sequence): Retransmission (suspected)
Previous segment not captured (common at capture start)
```

Is SFTP/SSH that sensitive to packet loss? Wouldn't SSH/SFTP retransmit/reacknowledge to avoid these packet loss errors? Is there something on the server settings I can tweak in order to make this work?

Comment: Since this is a question about a corporate, large scale network, it is [off topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) here. I am voting to migrate to http://serverfault.com.

Comment: Thank you Terdon. Should I create this question on serverfault.com myself or will this has to be migrated?

Comment: I have marked it for migration to server fault. If enough users agree, it will be moved automatically so you don't need to do anything. If you would prefer to have the question moved you can flag it for moderator attention and ask them to move it for you.

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer**:

You probably have an MTU/fragmentation problem. Try setting the MTU to 576 for the network interface on the client, eg `ifconfig eth0 mtu 576`.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the problem is a combination of asymetric routing and MTU issues.  What you describe does sound like an MTU issue.

You may be able to test/fix this by clamping your MTU - see the [here](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.cookbook.mtu-mss.html) for the appropriate hacks.

Comment: Thanks Davidgo. It happened to be an issue with packet fragmentation in the ISP side. One of their hop probably doesn't have the correct MTU set.